# NIO Http file server - connection closed prematurely

Tags: http, netty, nio, nanohttpd

I want to create an HTTP static file server using java NIO and it works fine for small files, but seems to truncate the HTTP response for larger files (672 KB out of a 3.8 MB image is returned according to my Chrome Inspector, and my browser displays a a partially corrupted image). Is this code below incorrect?

(I know there are existing libraries for this and eventually I will use one in my project. But initially I want to implement a basic one myself to see if my project concept is feasible.)

```
Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey key = keys.next();
    keys.remove();
    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
        // New Client encountered
        serverSocket.accept().configureBlocking(false)
                .register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

    } else if (key.isReadable()) {
        // Additional data for existing client encountered
        SocketChannel selectedClient = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(548);
        String requestedFile2 = getRequstedFile(key, selectedClient, buffer);
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.flip();

        FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(requestedFile2));
        String string = "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\nContent-Length: "
                + (Files.size(Paths.get(requestedFile2)) + "\n\n");
        selectedClient.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes()));
        while (fc.read(buffer) > -1) {
            buffer.flip(); // read from the buffer
            selectedClient.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
        selectedClient.close();

    }
}
```

(Exception handling etc. omitted for brevity)

**EDIT**

I have a content-length-mismatch error message. So what is the right way to determine the HTTP response size when reading a file's contents using the NIO API?

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer.clear();
```

That should be

```
buffer.compact();
```

and the loop should be

```
while (fc.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
```

You're assuming everything got written by the write.

Also you need to change the HTTP header line terminators to `\r\n`.

And you need to study RFC 2616 about the content length.

Comment: I made the 3 edits but now the browser doesn't show anything. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "copying data TO the file". I'm trying to read FROM the file. Are we talking about the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to check return value from selectedClient.write(), check the  SocketChannel.write() documentation:
*Unless otherwise specified, a write operation will return only after writing all of the r requested bytes. Some types of channels, depending upon their state, **may write only some of the bytes or possibly none at all.***

Which could be the case here. Either add another inner loop which would write to output as long as there are bytes remaining in the buffer. Or you can amend the loop according to example in ByteBuffer.compact(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#compact()

```
while (buffer.position() > 0 || fc.read(buffer) > 0) {
        buffer.flip(); // read from the buffer
        selectedClient.write(buffer);
        buffer.compact();
}
```

And remember that the code supposes that selectedClient is blocking. If that wasn't the case, you would need to invoke another select() waiting on the selectedClient becoming writable...